# Why systemd says that postfix failed, while postfix works perfectly well

Tags: debian, postfix, systemd

We are using the postfix mta on a debian server. Everything seems to work well (mail is sent and received), except that systemd says that the postfix@- service failed:

```
# systemctl restart postfix@-
Job for postfix@-.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postfix@-.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

# systemctl --failed
  UNIT              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● postfix@-.service loaded failed failed Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)
```

Here is the end of systemd configuration file postfix@.service:

```
...
[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=no
ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh %i
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postmulti -i %i -p start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postmulti -i %i -p stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postmulti -i %i -p reload
```

I tried running configure-instance.sh and postmulti by hand, they all return status 0

- Debian version = bullseye
- Postfix version = 3.5.6

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT** To be more precise, there are two systemd services: postscript and postscript@-

The following sequence is confusing for me:

```
root@pic2s:/var/log# postfix status
...
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 3341207

root@pic2s:/var/log# systemctl status postfix 
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-06-05 10:13:00 CEST; 1 day 5h ago
    Process: 3117705 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3117705 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 6ms

root@pic2s:/var/log# systemctl stop postfix
root@pic2s:/var/log# postfix status
...
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 3341207
```

So, to summarize:

- The postfix systemd service is **not** marked as failed
- When I stop the systemd service, postfix is **NOT** stopped
- The default instance is marked as failed by systemd

Comment: You quoted an error message that already includes a suggestion what to do: *See "systemctl status postfix@-.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*

Comment: Right. But just while I tried systemctl status postfix@-.service to show you the output... I discovered that now it works. I did not do anything except systemctl stop postfix and systemctl start postfix two or three times, and now it works, I do not know why.